# The package should not contain any .pem files with private keys except for the key.pem file in the root of the package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I recently made a chrome extension using react, but after trying to upload it, I get this error: 
The package should not contain any .pem files with private keys except for the key.pem file in the root of the package.

Comment: does the error mean anything to you? do you have `.pem` files in the package with private keys other than a file called `key.pem` in the root of the package?

Comment: Not that I know of. To be perfectly honest, I am a little lost on what .pem files are since I am relatively inexperienced to chrome extension dev.

Comment: It's a file with extension .pem

Comment: Thank you. They do indeed contain a .pem extension.

Comment: I'm getting this error too, but when I run `find . -name '*.pem'` I get nothing

Comment: Turns out it was in a symlinked directory